# Sending more than one key at the same time in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a script in VBScript that will send the keys CTRL and V at the same time, triggering the Paste thingy.

I tried something like:

```
Option Explicit
dim xx
set xx=createobject(wscript.shell)
xx.sendkeys("^V")
```

But it doesn't work. It just press CTRL and after that V, doing nothing. I want it to press them at the same time.

Would change anything if instead of "^V" I do "(^V)"? Or it will not? Please answer me!

Answer (score 1):

You've got some problems. Maybe they're just typos but...

```
Option Explicit
Dim xx
Set xx = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  ' Put quotes around WScript.Shell
xx.SendKeys "^v"                        ' Don't use parens without Call or a return assignment
```

That should do it. If it's still "doing nothing", you may want to try `AppActivate()` to activate the window you're trying to paste into.

```
If xx.AppActivate("Notepad") Then
    xx.SendKeys "^v"
End If
```